# How does this while loop iterate?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, stack, queue

Is this the right logic for the while loop:
 1. If the stack is not empty execute...
 2. Check that the element at the top of the stack == the element at the bottom of the queue.

And this will continue until either the stack/queue finishes first (if a palindrome, then they finish at the same time)? I thought that for the if(s.pop()....) that I'd have to iterate through with a for loop?

Cheers!

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    letter = word.charAt(i);
    s.push(i);
    q.add(i);
  }

  while (!s.isEmpty()) {
    if (s.pop()) != q.remove()) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: If `s` is your stack... What is `q`?

Comment: Start by explaining what you're trying to do.

Comment: You probably meant to use `letter` (not `i`) in your `push` and `add` calls. Also, `return new StringBuilder(word).reverse().toString().equals(word);` is a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code and yes your logic is write but it is using too much space you could have done it with the help of stack only there is no need of queue.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Stack;

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String word = "diid";
        Stack<Character> s = new Stack<>();
        Queue<Character> q = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char letter = word.charAt(i);
            s.push(letter);
            q.add(letter);
          }

          while (!s.isEmpty()) {
            if (s.pop() != q.remove()) {
              System.out.println("Not Palindrome");
              return;
            }
          }
          System.out.println("Palindrome");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the word is a palindrome, push all the characters to a stack then pop them to another string. The latter will be a reverse of the first one. So just check whether the 2 strings are the same.